# Validate Login form; Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Trying to validate my Login form with Jquery, when a error evaluates to true the error should slide down presenting the corresponding text however doesn't. I have managed to make this work on all other forms but for some reason it doesn't like this Login form.

CSS CODE

```
.error{
color: red;
padding: 2px;
text-align: left;
margin-left: 100px;
margin-top: 50px;
display: none;
height: 70px;
width: 400px;
float: left;
}
```

Login form

```
<form id="login_form" method="post" action="login.php">
    <fieldset><legend>Login</legend>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

    <br/>

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />

    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" />

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Jquery Code

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
     $('.error').slideDown("slow");
    });

 //Log In Validation
      $('#login_form').submit(function(e){

        // initialize error
        var error = false;

        $('.error').empty();

    if ($('#email').val() == "") {
        $('.error').append("<li>Please enter your email address</li>");
        error = true;
     }

     if ($('#password').val() == "") {
        $('.error').append("<li>Please enter a password<li>");
        error = true;

     }

     if (error) {
        e.preventDefault();
  }

});
```

Comment: what exactly is not working because I can't find the `.error` in your html?

Comment: Does your debug console throw any errors?

Comment: The Slidedown function. Sorry should of explained.

Comment: Where are you calling the slidedown function? The only thing you are doing when there is an error in your validation is `.append("...")`. You need to call the function. If you are calling it no matter what when the form is submitted with that `#submit`, you need to provide that ID to your submit button. If it were me, I would just call the dropdown function when you append the error to the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

submit button has no ID so selector used is not being found

Change to:

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" id="submit"/>
```

Comment: you should be using `on()` as well as `click()` and `submit()` were deprecated

Comment: @Phil where have you ever seen that those are deprecated? I do not believe that is true...would break a lot of sites

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete, maybe that's why it's not working:

1. You are missing your `.error` element, which your code is constantly looking for, so add `<div class="error"></div>` to your document.
2. Add `id="submit"` to your submit button.

But it doesn't seem that you're that familiar with jQuery, or coding at all, so if I were you, I would add this line:

`$('.error').slideDown("slow");` inside your `submit` function, rather than a `click` event on the submit button, since in reality, it does the same thing, but without the click, and catches the entire submit event, which is what you want. (In case they press enter, instead of clicking the button)

So you would remove these lines in the top of your js code:

```
 $('#submit').click(function(){
  $('.error').slideDown("slow"); 
 });
```

And add your slideDown function to when there actually is an error, like here (in your code):

```
 if (error) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.error').slideDown("slow"); // ADD IT HERE INSTEAD
 }
```

This makes it so it only makes the .error element viewable if there is an error, and once it has gathered all the errors.  And catches all submits, instead of just when someone clicks on the button, it also listens if they press enter in the form, which also triggers a submit. (And you wouldn't need to follow step #2 in the top of my answer either)